# How to find all labels that contain string in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to get all nodes of a certain label type.  I have roots of multiple graphs that all have the same suffix in their labels.  For example, i have 3 nodes that all have `treeroot` at the end of their label.  So I might have `companytreeroot`, `buildingtreeroot`, nd `employeetreeroot` as 3 valid labels for 3 distinct nodes.  How would I get all nodes whose label has that pattern?

I tried:

```
match (n) where '.*treeroot' in labels(n) return n
```

and

```
match (n) where 'treeroot' in labels(n) return n
```

but both return empty sets...

Comment: Unsure if this will help you, but nodes can be multi-labeled. If this is not free string matching, but instead a need to get nodes across multi similar labels at once, then you might consider adding a label to these nodes as a superlabel. Like adding a :TreeRoot label to all nodes with some treeroot label (companytreeroot, buildingtreeroot, employeetreeroot), and ensuring you add :TreeRoot to any new nodes of these labels as well. That will let your queries on these be more efficient than performing an entire graph scan.

Comment: Those matches will only check for full strings. @InverseFalcon's answer below is the most efficient. one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ANY function`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicates/#functions-any) for apply reqular expression to labels:

```
match (n) where ANY(l in labels(n) WHERE l =~ ".*treeroot")
return n
```

Answer (score 5):

stdob--'s answer works, but it must inspect all labels of all nodes in your graph, so this becomes more and more expensive as your graph grows.

A faster approach involves first finding the labels that match quickly by using the db.labels() procedure, then (because Cypher does not natively support dynamic label queries) use [APOC Procedures' cypher.run()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_cypher_execution) procedure to use String concatenation to assemble a query that finds all nodes in all the labels that met your match.

Here's an example that should be quite fast, even on large graphs:

```
CALL db.labels() YIELD label
WITH label
WHERE label ENDS WITH 'treeroot'
CALL apoc.cypher.run('MATCH (n:' + label + ') return n', null) YIELD value
RETURN value.n as node
```

Comment: @MichaelHunger It really is the golden hammer of Neo4j, much of the time.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Get a list of matching labels - a great idea! And thank you for pointing out the procedure "db.labels".